# AWS Docker Interpreter with Pycharm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, pycharm

I'm having difficulty to set this up correctly, and burning through AWS server time while I try to make it work.  I have segmentation code that is heavily memory intensive that I'd like to temporarily spin up an AWS server with 192GB of ram.  I understand that this is possible using docker, but the instructions on pycharm are non-existent with respect to the docker instructions necessary to tie it together (it references existing code as opposed to showing how to assemble it from scratch).  What would the docker run command on the server look like to enable a connection to the 2375 port?

EDIT: I am using Pycharm Professional

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:** Checking PyCharm options I found that there is an option to use Docker Machines. This seem to be exactly what you need. With Docker Machines you can make Docker spin up an EC2 instance for you with proper security out-of-the-box. Read official documentation on how to get started [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/examples/aws/#step-1-sign-up-for-aws-and-configure-credentials) and AWS driver options to learn how to set EC2 instance type, AMI, and other options [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/) .

**Original post:**

To enable this feature you have to run Docker daemon with '-H' option:

```sh
sudo dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

You may read more on that in the Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ .

Beware though, for EC2 you may also need to open that port using security group https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html .

I also want to add that what you want to achieve isn't good from security perspective. Exposing docker socket like that is like an invitation for bad guys to throw a party at your EC2 instance. But since you mentioned that this is temporary...

Comment: This will get your expensive cloud instance instantly rooted.  Anyone who can access that socket can do anything to your instance, as root, with no further authentication or logging, including running cryptocurrency miners at your expense and locking you out of the system entirely.

Comment: Better use TLS, relevant comment in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489#focus=Comments-27-4025896.0-0